# Properties of the Collatz map necessary to prove Collatz Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture, reverse-math

In complexity theory, there is the famous result that whether or not $\mathrm P = \mathrm{NP}$ is not a question that relativises; since there are oracles $O$ such that $\mathrm{P}^O = \mathrm{NP}^O$ and ones such that $\mathrm{P}^O \neq \mathrm{NP}^O$, any resolution of the problem must use some property of Turing machines which is not true of all Turing machines with oracles.

Somewhat similarly, I think, (although I do not claim to understand this) [sieve theory cannot be used to resolve the twin prime conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_problem_(sieve_theory)), and thus a resolution of the conjecture must necessarily use something else than sieve theory.

Is there something similar for the Collatz conjecture? Are there generalizations of the Collatz conjecture with a *lot* of similar properties for which the CC both holds and fails, depending on parameters?  Or can we rule out proof techniques which work for similar problems like for sieves?

Comment: When looking at general forms of the Collatz Conjecture, such as expanding 3x+1 to 3x+b, the generalization becomes horribly complex since for instance is 3x+5 is very different from 3x+1, not to mention 3x+3. Generalize it to ax+b and it becomes worse: 5x+1 blows up and 1x+1 is almost too convergent or too easy of a problem to solve. In a way, sieves may be helpful, assuming these sieves consider the right properties and that they too are not too daunting or too easy to solve.

Comment: I have the same intuition; namely that modular arithmetic cannot solve Collatz conjecture. I can't state it rigorously but I think the relationship at play transcends anything possible with modular arithmetic because the problem has a habit of, no matter what you do, always somehow managing to eek out a teeny tiny counterexample to your proof, whose resolution has an entirely new level of complexity to it. Terrence Tao said that he thinks some aspect of transcendence theory will need to be brought to bear on it; or its resolution may even shed new light on transcendental numbers.

Comment: To my knowledge the Twin Prime Conjecture is a totally different ball game than the Collatz Conjecture. But there is no point in ruling out Sieve Theory untill someone proves that it is worthless. My insight on the connection between sieves and CC is rather non-existent though. About the generalization as far as I know small changes to the equation make huge changes to the results after a few iterations. Considering these observations, personally I find it ineffective to focus on the generalizations, but rather put my attention on the standard collatz function problem.